# How to get input values of fields on click of that div's button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple product div with buttons having same onlick function.I want to get the values of the input fields on click of button.Both, input fields and button belong to same div.Currently i am getting values of very 1st product onclick of any button.Please help

```
<div class="buy" style="text-align:center;">
<span style="margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;" class="Lite_Price">$15.00</span>

<input type="hidden" maxlength="2" name="qty" class="quantity-wrp" id="itemqty" value="1">    
<input type="hidden" name="prod_id" id="prod_id" value="150">
<input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" value="151PM">
<input type="button" value="" onclick="promoproduct(this.id)" id="promo_button_1">
```

```
<div class="buy" style="text-align:center;">
<span style="margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;"   class="Lite_Price">$20.00</span>

<input type="hidden" maxlength="2" name="qty" class="quantity-wrp" id="itemqty" value="1">    
<input type="hidden" name="prod_id" id="prod_id" value="151">
<input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" value="152PM">
<input type="button" value="" onclick="promoproduct(this.id)" id="promo_button_2">
```

```
function promoproduct(clicked_id){

    var qty = $("#itemqty").val();
    var prod_id = $("#prod_idprod_id").val();
    var code = $("#code").val();
```

Comment: 1. id's must be unique, 2. remove return false after your console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Identifiers must be unique.**

You should pass the current element content `this` to inline click event handler. You can use common class and various traversal methods to target elements.

```
<input type="button" value="" onclick="promoproduct(this)" id="promo_button_2">
```

Then use relationship to target parent `buy` using `.parent()`/`.closest()` afterward using `.find()`

```
function promoproduct(clickedElem){
    var parent = $(clickedElem).closest(".buy");
    var qty =   parent.find('.quantity-wrp').val();
    var prod_id = parent.find('[name="prod_id"]').val();
    var code = parent.find('name="code"').val();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the `id` attribute should be unique in the same document, so you could use the general classes instead :

```
<div class="buy" style="text-align:center;">
    <span style="margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;"   class="Lite_Price">$20.00</span>

    <input type="hidden" maxlength="2" name="qty" class="quantity-wrp itemqty" value="1">    
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" class="prod_id" value="151">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" class="code" value="152PM">

    <input type="button" value="" onclick="promoproduct()" id="promo_button_2">
</div>
```

**NOTE :** No need to pass a parameter to the click function `promoproduct(this)` just pass `this` so you could get the current clicked element using `this` object inside your function.

You could use the `closest()` method to go up to the parent div `buy` then get the values :

```
function promoproduct(clicked_id){
    var parent_buy = $(this).closest(".buy");

    var qty =   parent_buy.find('.quantity-wrp').val();
    var prod_id = parent_buy.find('.prod_id').val();
    var code = parent_buy.find('.code').val(); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Snippet avoiding the use of the inline-event `onclick` :**

```js
$('.buy input:button').on('click',function(){
  var parent_buy = $(this).closest(".buy");
  
  var qty =   parent_buy.find('.quantity-wrp').val();
  var prod_id = parent_buy.find('.prod_id').val();
  var code = parent_buy.find('.code').val(); 

  console.log(qty,prod_id,code);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buy" style="text-align:center;">
  <span style="margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;"   class="Lite_Price">$20.00</span>

  <input type="hidden" maxlength="2" name="qty" class="quantity-wrp itemqty" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" class="prod_id" value="151">
  <input type="hidden" name="code" class="code" value="152PM">

  <input type="button" value="Promo product" id="promo_button_1">
</div>

<div class="buy" style="text-align:center;">
  <span style="margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;"   class="Lite_Price">$20.00</span>

  <input type="hidden" maxlength="2" name="qty" class="quantity-wrp itemqty" value="2">    
  <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" class="prod_id" value="252">
  <input type="hidden" name="code" class="code" value="255PM">

  <input type="button" value="Promo product" id="promo_button_2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have both buttons in different `divs` you can use the `parent` as reference to get the values from `input`.

Also when `calling function` you need to pass `this` not `this.id`

```
<div class="buy" style="text-align:center;">
<span style="margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;" class="Lite_Price">$15.00</span>

<input type="hidden" maxlength="2" name="qty" class="quantity-wrp" id="itemqty" value="1">    
<input type="hidden" name="prod_id" id="prod_id" value="150">
<input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" value="151PM">
<input type="button" value="" onclick="promoproduct(this)" id="promo_button_1">
</div>

<div class="buy" style="text-align:center;">
<span style="margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;"   class="Lite_Price">$20.00</span>

<input type="hidden" maxlength="2" name="qty" class="quantity-wrp" id="Hidden1" value="1">    
<input type="hidden" name="prod_id" id="Hidden2" value="151">
<input type="hidden" name="code" id="Hidden3" value="152PM">
<input type="button" value="" onclick="promoproduct(this)" id="promo_button_2">
</div>
    <script>
        function promoproduct(clicked_id) {

            var parent = $(clicked_id).closest("div.buy");
            var qty = $(parent).find("input[name=qty]").val();
            var prod_id = $(parent).find("input[name=prod_id]").val();
            var code = $(parent).find("input[name=code]").val();

        }
    </script>
```